# Validate cell based on another cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have this table

```
Counter    | String
---------------------
four       | Apple
six        | Banana
```

And want to validate the cells in the column `String` based on the value of the previous cell in the same row `Counter` Column.

**What I did?**

-> Data -> Data Validation -> Custom
and here's the formula i've written

```
=AND(LEN(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))=4, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)) = "four")
```

But it doesn't work with me, anyone can help me in that?

Comment: Instead of the word "four" and "six", why not make life easier and use 4 and 6? Much easier to validate the number returned by `LEN()` against an actual number.

Comment: Actually, i'm not using `counter` like four or six i'm using a different use case similar to this.

Comment: Then please create a piece of sample data that does reflect your use case instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDIRECT` returns the cell reference rather than the cell value. Used in a cell this is not really a difference but used elsewhere there can be problems. In your case the cell reference is not equal "four" but the value behind that cell reference is. To solve those problems you can wrap the `INDIRECT` in `N` or `T` dependent of whether the result is numeric or text.

So in your case:

```
=AND(LEN(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))=4,T(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))="four")
```

This should work if applied to the column `String`.

But massive using `INDIRECT` should be avoided because of it's volatile behavior. Most times it can be replaced using `INDEX`. So also in this case.

```
=AND(ROW()<10,COLUMN()<27,INDEX($A$1:$Z$9,ROW(),COLUMN()-1)="four")
```

should be the same.